# Events from Firebase Analytics don't showing up in Big Query

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have a trouble when I linked Firebase Events to Big Query.

1. In Firebase Analytics, I have many event .
2. I linked firebase with Big Query
3. But in Big Query, I can't see it.
4. How can I see it?

I tried to unlink bigquery and put it back. I tried to follow every tutorial, but there is nothing to do, my events don't appear and I don't know why

1. [my 25 events in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1xl2M.png)
2. [events that I apparently export from firebase, but they have nothing to do with those in firebase](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mb5Wf.png)

So If somebody knows how to realy export their events from firebase it would be a pleasure :)

PS : sorry for my english, I hope I don't made too much wording mistakes

Answer (score 2):

It appears that data from Firebase is exported to BigQuery when it is beyond a certain number as you can see only screenView event is getting recorded in Big Query which has a high number of event count. It takes some time for the data to accumulate and get displayed as it is not recorded in real time as Firebase. If the linking has been done properly then the data will start to show up as soon as it is beyond that number.

Answer (score 1):

Analytics events are exported from Firebase to BigQuery from the moment you enable the integration. There is no way to export events from before you enabled the integration.